# Showing the Delete button in UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView.

When I move my mouse from right to left on cell it is not displaying the delete button.

Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:
```

I've found a topic of somebody that had the same problem as you..
See [this thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7557-how-enable-swipe-delete-tableview-cell.html)